# Closest to a number from user inputs

Tags: python, algorithm

So I wanted to know if it was possible to take 3 numbers from the user all ranging from 1-6 and take 1 more input from the user ranging from 1 - 144 and make a program that takes the first 3 numbers you got and finds a way using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, roots, and powers to find a way, using the 3 numbers, to get the 4th user input. If you can't get the 4th user input find the closest that you can get to it from the first 3 inputs.Then the program should tell you the operations it used and which numbers it used it on. This is basically recreating the game ThinkFun Math Dice.

For example: If the first 3 numbers the user inuts are 5, 2, and 9 and the 4th number is 86, the program should do 9^2 which is 81 and 81+5 which is 86. In another case if the 3 numbers are 6, 4, and 2 and the the final answer is(4th input)24, the program should do 6*4 -2 or 6*4 +2 or 4^2+6 since these all equal to 26 or 22 and there is no possible solution to get 24.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of how it should work?

Comment: Ok I added some examples.

Comment: You could formulate this as a search problem. I don't have time to write a full example, but you'd have an implicit graph where the nodes were the three numbers plus the operations on those numbers. A child node is created by applying one of your mathematical operations on the result using the three values. Search terminates if you find the target value

Comment: The logic has 24*5  possible combinations. you can hard-code these combinations or use nested loops and ifs. then look into 120 answers and find what you looking for. It's late i can't work on structure but consider combinations as following: each of these have 5 possible comnibination with the third number <br> a+b  
a+c   
b+c

a*b
a*c
b*c

a-c
a-b
b-c
c-a
b-a
c-b

a/c
a/b
b/c
c/a
b/a
c/b

a ** c
a ** b
b ** c
c ** a
b ** a
c ** b

Comment: @DataScienceStep Where do you get 24*5 from?  With 3 numbers, 6 operations and possible parentheses, there are actually 432 possibilities.  You can see that by writing everything in RPN notation.  You have 6 choices of operator for the top operation, 6 for the second, 2 places the second operation can go, and 6 ways to arrange the 3 numbers on the stack.  There are somewhat less if you consider that `+` and `*` are commutative operations.

Comment: This is all getting very confusing...

Comment: I didn't considered root operator as it's less likely to be useful. but when I was in bed I thought it will become easier if we calculate all possibilities in loops and add all the answers in a list with saving used operand along with answer. I wish I had time to try write the core algorithm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While btilly's answer is absolutely correct, it is a bit more than what's needed for this problem, at least in python. Using the itertools library and the `eval()` function, you can get by with a much shorter and simpler approach. Do note that `eval()` and `exec()` are considered insecure, since they will execute anything passed, however as a script for personal use it should be fine. Any malicious code would probably trip an exception casting the inputs to ints anyways.
from itertools import permutations

```
coeffs = list(map(int, input("Coefficents, separated by spaces:\n").split()))
target = int(input("Target value:\n"))

operators = ["({}+{})","({}-{})","({}*{})","({}/{})","({}**{})","({}**(1.0/{}))"]

def make_expr(expr, coeffs, target):
    if not coeffs:
        try:
            return eval(expr), expr
        except OverflowError:
            return None
        except ArithmeticError:
            return None

    solutions =  [make_expr(op.format(expr, coeffs[0]), coeffs[1:], target) for op in operators]
    solutions += [make_expr(op.format(coeffs[0], expr), coeffs[1:], target) for op in operators]
    solutions = [x for x in solutions if x is not None]
    val, expr = min(solutions, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-target))
    return val, expr

def find_best(coeffs, target):
    assert(len(coeffs) > 1)
    solutions = [make_expr(perm[0], perm[1:], target) for perm in permutations(coeffs)]
    solutions = [x for x in solutions if x is not None]
    val, expr = min(solutions, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-target))
    return "Closest value: {0}\nExpression: {1}".format(val, expr)

print(find_best(coeffs, target))
```

To support more operators, just insert them into the list, with `{}`'s where the arguments go, and surrounded by paretheses. I've added support for extra operators, however since I do not shortcut the iteration when it finds a perfect solution, it can take a very long time for 3+ operators.

Comment: When I entered 6 6 6 for the a,b,c and 55 for the target number, the program told me that the closest is ((6+6)*6) even though the closest is actually (6(6*6)).

Comment: I cannot reproduce that specific issue. When I try with those values, I actually get a division by zero error. After throwing eval in a try-except block, it proceeds to produce ((6*6)+6), giving 42. I've updated the answer to contain cleaner code that handles those exceptions and can support an arbitrary number of inputs. I can only hope that it somehow fixes the issue since I can't reproduce it. Please let me know if it still does not work.

Comment: Coefficents, separated by spaces: 9 8 7
 Target value: 10
 --> Output: none, loops forever

Comment: Its not in an infinite loop- its just hanging on the exponential combinations, which are quite large and take python some time to calculate. In this case it likely `(7**(8**9))`. I suppose you can implement a timeout class if you want to handle larger numbers, or apply a cutoff for exponentiation. It will eventually return the correct answer regardless-  it just might take awhile.

Comment: You could also replace the exponentiation operator with something like `{0}**{1} if {1} < 1e3 else 1/0`, however provides a scenario where all operators on the last term raise an exception, causing `min()` to be passed an empty list, in turn raising an exception. More try-except blocks could fix this, or replacing `None` with some extremely large value that won't ever be the best-case would fix it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the problem is to decide what format to use to write out the possible calculations, list them, try each one, and select the best.

I'm going to suggest RPN notation because it is simple to work with.  I've given you the code to list possible calculations in RPN notation.  You still need to do IO and write an RPN calculator.  IO is easy.  There are lots of examples of RPN calculators online that you can study.

```
def list_perms (args):
    if 0 == len(args):
        yield []
    else:
        x = args[0]
        for p in list_perms(args[1:]):
            for i in range(0, len(p)+1):
                yield p[:i] + [x] + p[i:]


def list_rpn (x, y, z):
    ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^', 'r']
    for p in list_perms([x, y, z]):
        for op1 in ops:
            for op2 in ops:
                yield p + [op1, op2]
                yield p[0:2] + [op1, p[2], op2]

def evaluate (calc):
    return 'you have to figure this out'

def find_best (x, y, z, r):
    best_val = x+y+z
    best_calc = [x, y, z, '+', '+']
    for calc in list_rpn(5, 6, 8):
        try:
            val = evaluate(calc)
            if val == r:
                return calc
            elif abs(val - r) < abs(best_val - r): 
                best_val = val
                best_calc = calc
        except Exception:
            # Throw exceptions on things like divide by 0, or powers of
            # negative numbers that aren't n or 1/n where n is an odd number
            pass

    return best_calc

# You should also do proper IO here.
print(find_best(5, 2, 9, 24))
```